# How do I read developer responses to my app reviews?

Tags: ios-appstore, apple-id

Is there a way to view all of your developer responses in the App Store?

Comment: You are supposed to get an email (to the address of the Apple ID) with the response. Did you get that?  Check your spam folder, too.

Comment: I didn't got an email, but notifications. On all of my devices. Even on my mac. So I clicked it, but it didn't go anywhere - I suppose because it's an iOS app.
When I tapped the notification on my iPhone, it opened the app store site of the app but not the review itself. Poor UX, Apple!

Comment: I’ve had this happen, too. A notification on the iPhone says “you have received a developer response,” but when you click on it, it takes you to the App Store, to the app in question, but doesn’t show my review, or the response from the developer.

Answer (score 6):

I was wondering this too, check your junk mail I found the response in there :)

Answer (score 0):

If you know the app of which review was replied, you can try to open that app's page in App Store -> press "All reviews" -> change sorting to "Sort by recent" -> try to find it in the list and see the reply.

Answer (score -2):

Check your cloud junk mail. It’s there.

Comment: This is that same as the earlier answer https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/392520/237